# Defining two id's to one piece of css code

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was any way of defining two section id's to a piece of css code.

At the moment the code is exactly the same apart from the id, is there any way to have both id's in one piece of the code rather than duplicating the same code. e.g

## slider#nav ul

```
#slider ul {
list-style-type:none;
height:80px;
width:620px;
background: rgb(206,220,231); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%, rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(206,220,231,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(89,106,114,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cedce7', endColorstr='#596a72',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px ; 
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px ;
opacity:0.8;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
height:80px;
width:620px;
background: rgb(206,220,231); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%, rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(206,220,231,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(89,106,114,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(206,220,231,1) 0%,rgba(89,106,114,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cedce7', endColorstr='#596a72',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px ; 
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px ;
opacity:0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply by adding a comma.

```
#nav ul, #slider ul {
//Code
}
```

You code will now be applied to both id's

Comment: I don't know where the other answer went but the code he supplied worked but I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Happy to have helped anyway.